# Script PowerShell to connect to multiple HP ProCurve switches using SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh

I would like to connect to multiple HP switches using SSH.
First of all, I need to connect to a server using SSH. I use `plink`:

```
putty\plink.exe -ssh user@x.x.x.x -pw psss
```

I need a file with IP list of switch.

When I'm connected to server, I have to use `plink` to connect to HP switch:

```
putty\plink.exe -ssh user@x.x.x.x -pw psss < .\commands.txt >> .\output.txt 2>>&1
```

`commands.txt` file contains these commands:

```
display device maninfo
```

Can you help me finalize this code?

Comment: Are you looking for `Get-Content ip_list.txt | ForEach-Object { ... }`?

Comment: If you've never heard of it, putty has a wrapper called superputty. It can have an explorer tree and you can right click and connect to multiples in a list instantly. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

As ansgar said

```
Foreach ($ip in (cat c:\iplist.txt) {
    putty\plink.exe -ssh user@$ip -pw psss
}
```

Is what you're likely wanting.